# Can't display api data to a chart (Chartjs)

Tags: javascript, charts

The chart it is showing only the fell information and marking the data numbers in datasets in the donut. What I am looking for is that the chart shows the values ​​of found and fell (from the api). I have tried to delete those parameters and change it but it is not reflected. also above the chart there are many small rectangles with the values ​​of found and fell

```
async function getMeteor() {
  const url = 'https://data.nasa.gov/resource/gh4g-9sfh.json'

  const result = await fetch(url)
  const barChartData = await result.json()
  
  const falling = barChartData.map( (x) => x.fall)
  return falling;
}

async function printChart() {
  const fallData = await getMeteor();
  const data = {
  labels: fallData,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Fell Meteors',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
  }]
};

const config = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: data,
  options: {}
};

const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);
  
}



printChart();
```

Comment: You need to do something like this, https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/PoRLVwy

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `document.getElementById('myChart')` to

```
document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
```